# Permutation of a 2 dimensional arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, permutation

I'm trying to make a 2 dimensional array list that is filled with every possible combination of lets say 1,2,3,4 recursively.
with no double ups.

for example.
1,0,0
2,0,0
3,0,0
4,0,0
1,2,0
1,3,0
1,4,0
1,2,3
etc...

so far I have

```
//this gives me all my numbers
for(int i =0;i<arraySize;i++)
index[i] = i;

// and is the part that make the combinations
for(int i = 0;i<arraySize;i++){
   for(int x = 0;x<k;x++)
      combinations.get(i).set(x, index[i]);
```

EDIT:
Also I'm not trying to print the result I want to store the result in a 2 dimensional array

Comment: You have one `ArrayList` and try to get all permutations between its elements ?

Comment: You want a list of "possible combination of lets say 1,2,3,4 " but in your example you have put:  1,0,0  .  As 0 is not in the original list should it also therefore not be in the output? :)

Comment: @Sephy I have the array "index" which is just 1 to whatever the length of my object array is and I have combinations which is a 2 dimensional array list which I want to be fill with all the possible combinations of "index".

Comment: @user2777005 I was trying to make the point that I don't want 
111
112
113
I need 
1
2
3
the zero's would be null

Comment: This seems to be more like a counter than a permutation -- that is, you allow "incomplete" words such as "1" or "12". Are words such as "21" allowed, or are you enforcing that digits have to be in increasing order?

Answer (score 2):

Another, non-recursive option. I use "words" for (partial) permutations and "symbols" for numbers:

```
/**
 * Expands the set of existing words by adding non-repeated symbols to their right
 * @param symbols to choose from
 * @param existing words (may include the empty word)
 * @param expanded result 
 */
public static void expand(ArrayList<Integer> symbols, 
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> existing, 
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> expanded) {
    for (ArrayList<Integer> prev : existing) {
        Integer last = prev.isEmpty() ? null : prev.get(prev.size()-1);
        for (Integer s : symbols) {
            if (last == null || s > last) {
                ArrayList<Integer> toAdd = new ArrayList<>(prev);
                toAdd.add(s);
                expanded.add(toAdd);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> symbols = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> prev = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> next = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> aux;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<>();
    // add empty
    prev.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    // expand empty, then expand that expansion, and so on and so forth
    for (int i=0; i<symbols.size(); i++) {
        expand(symbols, prev, next);
        output.addAll(next);
        aux = prev; prev = next; next = aux;
        next.clear();
    }
    // print result (note: only for debugging purposes)
    for (ArrayList<Integer> o : output) {
        for (int i : o) System.out.print(i);  System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And the output matches the original question (which does *not* seem to be asking for actual permutations, at least according to the provided example):

```
1
2
3
4
12
13
14
23
24
34
123
124
134
234
1234
```

Comment: Note that the expansion rule can be tweaked to produce an actual counter ("all words, even incomplete, with allowed digits"). I am currently enforcing ascending sequences, because all supplied examples are ascending sequences...

Comment: This is the result I am trying to achieve. I want all those combinations in a 2 dimensional array or array list so I can use the values individually as kind of pointers to the index's of values in an object array

Comment: The `output` ArrayList is exactly what you are asking for `output.get(rowIndex).get(colIndex)` yields the integer corresponding to a particular pair of row/column index. Beware that not all rows (= possible combinations) have the same length.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called [Backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). This problem-solving technique is heavily based on recursion. Basically, you set your first number, then only consider the other numbers as a sub-problem, and when every permutation has been found with that first number set, this first number is incremented, etc.

You can also solve the problem with a straight-forward 4 for-loops, but the solution will not scale to anything else than 4 numbers.

Your solution would be something like what follows. It will output every permutation of 4 numbers.

```
public class PermutationDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[4];

        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            reset(array, i);
        }

        solve(array, 0);
    }

    private static void solve(int[] array, int i) {
        if (i == array.length) {
            print(array);
            return;
        }

        for (int k=0; k<4; k++) {
            solve(array, i+1);
            makeMove(array, i);
        }

        reset(array, i);
    }

    private static void makeMove(int[] array, int i) {
        array[i] += 1;
    }

    private static void reset(int[] array, int i) {
        array[i] = 1;
    }

    private static void print(int[] array) {
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
PS [10:21] Desktop > java PermutationDemo
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 1 4
1 2 1
1 2 2
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 1
1 3 2
1 3 3
1 3 4
1 4 1
1 4 2
1 4 3
1 4 4
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 1 3
2 1 4
2 2 1
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 2 4
2 3 1
2 3 2
2 3 3
2 3 4
2 4 1
2 4 2
2 4 3
2 4 4
3 1 1
3 1 2
3 1 3
3 1 4
3 2 1
3 2 2
3 2 3
3 2 4
3 3 1
3 3 2
3 3 3
3 3 4
3 4 1
3 4 2
3 4 3
3 4 4
4 1 1
4 1 2
4 1 3
4 1 4
4 2 1
4 2 2
4 2 3
4 2 4
4 3 1
4 3 2
4 3 3
4 3 4
4 4 1
4 4 2
4 4 3
4 4 4
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I am trying to do but in a 2 dimensional array because I need to compare the combinations to the index's of an object array to find the most optimal combination of items.

Answer (score 0):

As a general tip about operations on collections in java, I would advise you to look the utility classes from [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) which does most of the heavy-lifting for you and ensure you don't have performance issues you don't understand.

Then, the next step is looking to find a method that suits your need. For instance, [Collections2.permutations](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#permutations%28java.util.Collection%29) might be what you are looking for.

Finally, if you want to implement this yourself as an algorithmic exercise maybe, you can look at the source for guava or Groove Collection API to get ideas.