# Select all combinations of elements

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

There is a list of `MyOption` elements:

```
class MyOption{
   List<Integer> listElements;
}
```

then I have two values `allElements` and `selectedElements`. The first is size of `listElements` and the second means how many list's items have value=0(others are null). 
I have to get `List<MyOption>` which every combination of notnull elements. I know that there are always

`(  allElements!  /  (selectedElements! * (allElements - selectedElements)!  )` combinations.

For example, for `allElements=3` and `selectedElements=1` there are:
`3!/(1!*(3-1))! = 3` combinations (`listElements` has size 3 and `List<MyOption>` has size 3 too):

```
0      null   null
null     0    null
null   null    0
```

and the second example for `allElements=4` and `selectedElements=2`, there are 6 combinations:

```
0      0     null  null
0     null    0    null
0     null   null   0
null   0      0    null
null   0     null   0
null  null    0     0
```

How is it possible to get all of them when I know `allElements` and `selectedElements`?

Comment: I believe this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653320/permutation-of-a-2-dimensional-arraylist) may help you. You want to think "Permutations".

Answer (score 0):

There is a [recursive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_definition) of the binomial coefficient which yields a solution to your problem:

```
public static long choose(long allElements, long selectedElements){
    if(allElements < selectedElements)
        return 0;
    if(selectedElements == 0 || selectedElements == allElements)
        return 1;
    return choose(allElements-1,selectedElements-1)+choose(allElements-1,selectedElements);
}
```

Note: this is an easy to understand approach which will work fine for small inputs, there are more efficient implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution using recursion.

```
private static void combinations(ArrayList<Integer> solution, int selectedElements, int start, ArrayList<List<Integer>> solutions) {
  if(selectedElements < 1) {
    solutions.add(new ArrayList<>(solution));
  } else {
    for(int i = start; i < solution.size() - selectedElements + 1; i++) {
      solution.set(i, 0);
      combinations(solution, selectedElements - 1, i+1, solutions);
      solution.set(i, null);
    }
  }
}
static List<List<Integer>> combinations(int allElements, int selectedElements) {
  ArrayList<List<Integer>> solutions = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayList<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i = 0; i < allElements; i++) solution.add(null);
  combinations(solution, selectedElements, 0, solutions);
  return solutions;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<List<Integer>> solutions = combinations(4, 2);
  System.out.println(solutions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In c++, you may use `std::next_permutation`, something like:

```
std::vector<int> v {0, 0, 1, 1};

do {
    print(v);
} while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(v), std::end(v)));
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/3XFYt2)

Comment: Or just use Scala. Then it's only one line: `List(0,0,null,null).permutations`